# Can I see which sqls has been executed in postgres when pg_dump run

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want to get the DDL sql in postgres like show create table `test` in mysql.
I found pg_dump can get the sql about create table.
But I want to get the sql executed by pg_dump.
How can I get this sql?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statements run by pg_dump, run pg_dump --verbose.

If you want to see all SQL statements run in PostgreSQL instance for all databases set log_statement=all in postgresql.conf and run pg_ctl reload.